# How can I make my app made with react js and vite, to a PWA?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite

I've been reading a bit about it but I don't know how to configure correctly to convert my reactjs website to PWA

I've created a workbox-config.js file at the root of my project, and a manifest.json file at the top of my App.js, but I don't know what else to do

The content of the workbox-config.js file is:

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "dist/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{html,js,css,svg,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}"
  ],
  "swDest": "dist/sw.js",
  "clientsClaim": true,
  "skipWaiting": true,
  "navigateFallback": "/index.html",
  "navigateFallbackWhitelist": [/^\/(about|contact)$/],
  "runtimeCaching": [
    {
      "urlPattern": /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
      "handler": "StaleWhileRevalidate"
    },
    {
      "urlPattern": /^https:\/\/my-api\.com/,
      "handler": "NetworkFirst",
      "options": {
        "cacheName": "api-cache",
        "networkTimeoutSeconds": 10
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install vite-plugin-pwa and modify the vite.config.js file as described in this article:

["Turn your react + vite app into a PWA"](https://dev.to/bhendi/turn-your-react-vite-app-into-a-pwa-3lpg)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).